# Inherent Pitfall of Lebesgue Integration?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I am studying Real Analysis with Royden's Book. I noticed that for a function $f$ differentiable almost everywhere on $[a, b]$ and $f'$ integrable over $[a, b],$ it does not imply that $ f(x) = \int_{[a, x]}f'(t)\,dt + f(a).$ Take Cantor function $f$ as a counter example, since $1 = f(1) > \int_{[0, 1]}f'(t)\,dt + f(0) = 0,$ because $f'(x) = 0 $ $ \forall x \in [0,1]$. However, does it mean that Lebesgue integral has some inherent pitfall in the definition of integration? In a sense that it fails to restore the original picture of a function in a set of measure zero after differentiation. Is that any better (or more general) design of integration? so that we can guarantee $ f(x) = \int_{[a, x]}f'(t)\,dt + f(a)$.

Comment: It is reasonable to me that integration cannot deal with those "jump points" since we can never tell how much the original function jumps by its derivative. However, the problem with Cantor function is that it "jumps" at uncountably many points with measure zero, and Lebesgue Integration fails to detect it since everything happens in a set of measure zero. It makes thinking if we can define something that can work on sets with measure zero.

Answer (score 5):

When we get to Lebesgue integration, we typically do so because we have identified pathologies in which the (conventional) Riemann integration fails. It is a natural question to ask whether the Lebesgue integral belongs to a measure theoretic version of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. And while at first it may not appear to be a big deal, it doesn't really make sense to attempt to establish the fundamental theorem of calculus using measure-theoretic (Lebesgue) integration and conventional differentiation.

Indeed, the standard way of defining a derivative uses limits of ratios of differences; differences make sense when we have well-defined sets and the notion of measure coincides with our notion of 1-dimensional absolute value. So it instead might make sense to explore not a different kind of integration, but a different kind of *differentiation* that works in a measure theoretic sense.

This is in fact the essence of the Radon-Nikodym derivative. This derivative uses the fact that given a measurable set $E$ and a measurable function $f$, the mapping $E \mapsto \int_E f\, d\mu$ is a signed measure, and we denote this relationship with the notation $d\nu = fd\mu$; moreover, it is true that given $\sigma$-finite measures $\mu$, $\nu$, with $\nu$ positive and $\nu = 0$ whenever $\mu = 0$, that we can write 
$$d\nu = \frac{d\nu}{d\mu}d\mu.$$
We call $\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}$ the Radon-Nikodym derivative.
Note, this is actually a special case of a slightly more broad statement.

Using a bit more care in restricting our domain, we can actually develop an analog to the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, known as the Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem, which states that for a locally integrable function $f$, for a.e. $x$, we have $\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{1}{m(E_r)} \int_{E_r} f(y)\, dy = f(x)$ for every $E_r$ that "shrinks nicely" to $x$.

So we can do what you want to do, but we have to use a notion of the derivative that melds with what we do in a measure theoretic sense. You can't play basketball with hockey pucks, but you can sometimes play both in the same arena.

Answer (score 0):

That's the distinction between a function being everywhere differentiable and almost everywhere differentiable. You can still recover something from almost everywhere differentiability if you impose the extra condition of absolute continuity. It's a stronger version of continuity that excludes pathologies like the Cantor function. If $f$ is absolutely continuous, then it has a derivative almost everywhere and $ \displaystyle f(x) = f(a) + \int_a^x f^{\prime}(t) \, dt$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am just wondering if we do not impose any stronger restriction, is it still possible to restore the original function with integrating the derivative.

Comment: No, the only requirement is absolute continuity. If you think about what absolute continuity is, you'll realize that when we ask  whether a function is absolutely continuous, we're asking whether or not we will lose some of the change in the function by differentiating and then integrating (like the cantor function, which only ever increases at discontinuities).

Comment: You can, but it would require appealing to the theory of generalized functions. We can identify $df$ with a linear functional on the space of continuous functions with compact support, namely as the functional that satisfies $(df, \phi) = -(f, d\phi)$ for every function $\phi$ that is continuous and has compact support (think of integration by parts). The downside is that $df$ might no longer be meaningful as a function in the usual sense.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. If $f$ is everywhere differentiable on $[a,b]$ and $f'\in L^1([a,b]),$ then $f(b)-f(a) = \int_a^b f'.$
2. There exists an everywhere differentiable, strictly increasing function $f$ on $[a,b]$ with $f'$ bounded, such that $f'$ is not Riemann integrable on $[a,b].$ The Lebesgue integral doesn't care: $f(b)-f(a) = \int_a^b f'$ still holds by 2.